# How can I create a VBA function (for Access 2010) that exports pass-through queries as XML files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ms-access, vba

Currently, I am using Access 2010. I have used TSQL to create and store several pass-through queries.

Before, I was using the following VBA to export native (to Access 2010) "select" queries on a regular basis:

```
Sub ExportToXmlFile()
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, DataSource:="Query1", DataTarget:="C:\Desktop\Query1.xml"
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, DataSource:="Query2", DataTarget:="C:\Desktop\Query2.xml"
End Sub
```

However, ever since I reworked Query1 and Query2 as pass-through queries, I receive the following run-time error: "7798: You can only save select, crosstab, and union queries to this format".

Therefore, I would like to know how I can rewrite the aforementioned VBA in order to be able to export my pass-through queries as XML files?

Notes:

I stumbled upon the following during my research on this problem:
[Can't export a pass through query...Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.ms-access/ZJiz5Y8bCIM)

It seems like a possible solution is to store the pass-through query as a temporary table, and then export the temporary table as an XML file. Unfortunately, I have been trying to rewrite the VBA above to do so, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discovered `ExportXML` will not accept a pass-through query.  However, at least in Access 2007, you can work around that limitation fairly easily by creating a new query which uses the pass-through as its data source.  Then `ExportXML` will accept the new query without complaint.

Create and save this query as *qryFromPassthru*:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Query1;
```

Then use *qryFromPassthru* with `ExportXML`:

```vb
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, _
    DataSource:="qryFromPassthru", DataTarget:="C:\Desktop\Query1.xml"
```